# Меняется value в зависимости от выбора

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть yandex форма для оплаты. Пытаюсь сделать так что бы при выборе `банковская карта` или `яндекс деньги` в форме менялся `value="Имя платежа"`

Допустим выбрали банковская карта - `name="formcomment" value="OOO Банк"`,
Выбрали яндекс деньги `name="formcomment" value="Yandex"`

```
     <form id="request_form" action="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml" method="POST" data-form="request" data-type="jsonp" onsubmit="" class="direct request-form js-request-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="ID">      
        <input type="hidden" name="quickpay-form" value="small">
        <input type="hidden" name="formcomment" value="Имя платежа">    
        <input type="hidden" name="targets" value="Demo pay">  
        <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="10" data-type="number">  

         <select name="paymentType" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="AC">Банковской картой</option>
            <option value="PC">Яндекс.Деньгами</option>
        </select>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name="formcomment"]')
  .val( $('select=[name="paymentType"] selected').text() )
```

Это если jQuery